# RegEx to match wp-content

Tags: regex, wordpress

here is the situaltion.

Im tring to match /wp-content using regex

here is what i have

```
/^/wp-content[a-zA-Z]*/
```

Please anybody help

**match:** url("/wp-content/upload/")

**no match** url("https://example.com/wp-content/upload/")

Thanks

**Update**

I like to search in

```
$string = '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/client-logos/white/ens-industrial-white.png" alt="ENS Industrial Logo">';
```

where it matched wp-content and replace.

My string is entire HTML content.

I only want to match if is exact `/wp-content/`

also need to check and make sure that there is nothing in front of `/wp-conent`, only match if its like

Comment: Please update your Question or comment under the propose Answer... Do not add Comments as new Answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below PHP script.

```
$string = '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/client-logos/white/ens-industrial-white.png" alt="ENS Industrial Logo">';
preg_match('/<img(.*)src(.*)=(.*)"(.*)"/U', $string, $result);
$img_url = array_pop($result);

if (preg_match("/^\/\wp-content(.*)/", $img_url)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: I have modified my script and you can try it.